# How to disable scroll on body when fullscreen menu open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can anyone tell me how to disable scrolling when you open a fullscreen menu? The below code is what i currently have. I need to disable scrolling on desktop and mobile while the menu is open as at the moment you can scroll when its open, and will unknowingly end up on a different part of the page when you close the menu.

```css
:root {
  --color-secondary: #75757C;
  --color-dark: #364C62;
  --color-light: #F5F5F5;
  --td: 150ms;
  --te: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}


.page-container > * + * {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}
 
.navigation-container {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-main {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  left: -100%;
  position: fixed;
  transition: left 0s calc(var(--td) * 2), transform 0s calc(var(--td) * 2);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.nav-main::before, .nav-main::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: #0e0e0e;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-110%);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transition: transform calc(var(--td) * 2) var(--td) var(--te);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -100;
}
.nav-main::before {
  top: -7%;
}
.nav-main::after {
  bottom: 0;
}
.nav-main .menu__item {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-1rem);
  transition: opacity var(--td) var(--te), transform var(--td) var(--te);
}

[id="main-navigation-toggle"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0rem;
  top: 0rem;
  z-index: 100;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label span {
  display: block;
  height: 125px;
  padding: 0rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform calc(var(--td) * 3) var(--te);
  width: 2.7rem;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label span::before, [id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label span::after {
  background-color: #FB4D98;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transition: transform calc(var(--td) * 3) var(--te);
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 1rem);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    

[id="main-navigation-toggle"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label span {
  display: block;
  height: 27px;
  right: -8px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform calc(var(--td) * 3) var(--te);
  width: 2.7rem;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label span::before, [id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label span::after {
  background-color: #FB4D98;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transition: transform calc(var(--td) * 3) var(--te);
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 1rem);
}
}

[id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label span::before {
  transform: rotate(0) translateY(-100%);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label span::after {
  transform: rotate(0) translateY(100%);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ label span {
  transform: rotate(1turn);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ label span::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ label span::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main {
  left: 0;
  transition: transform 0s;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main::before, [id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main::after {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main::after {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) / 0);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main .menu__item {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: opacity calc(var(--td) * 2) var(--te), transform calc(var(--td) * 2) var(--te);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main .menu__item:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) * 2 * (1 * 0.25));
  z-index: -1;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main .menu__item:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) * 2 * (2 * 0.25));
  z-index: -2;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main .menu__item:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) * 2 * (3 * 0.25));
  z-index: -3;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main .menu__item:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) * 2 * (4 * 0.25));
  z-index: -4;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main .menu__item:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) * 2 * (5 * 0.25));
  z-index: -5;
}
.menu {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu > .menu__item {
  font-family: alliance !important;
  font-size: 10vmin;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .menu {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top:-7%;
  z-index: 1;
}
}
.submenu {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-10%);
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}
.submenu .menu__item {
  font-family: var(--font-family-primary);
  font-size: 3.5vmin;
  width: 100%;
}
.submenu .menu__link {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 var(--color-primary), 2px 2px 0 var(--color-primary);
}
.submenu .menu__link::before, .submenu .menu__link::after {
  display: none;
}
.menu__item {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.menu__item:hover .menu__link::before, .menu__item:hover .menu__link::after {
  animation: blink 1s var(--td) steps(1, end) forwards infinite;
  transform: translateX(calc(100% - 0.5rem));
  transition-duration: calc(var(--td) * 3);
}
.menu__item:hover .menu__link::after {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) / 2);
}
.menu__item:hover .submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform calc(var(--td) * 2) calc(var(--td) * 3) var(--te), opacity calc(var(--td) * 2) calc(var(--td) * 3) var(--te), visibility 0s calc(var(--td) * 3);
  visibility: visible;
}
.menu__link {
  color: #F4FB82;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 0.125rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color var(--td) var(--te), opacity var(--td) var(--te), transform var(--td) var(--te);
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu__link::before, .menu__link::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: #fb4d98;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-110%);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transition: transform 0s var(--te);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.menu__link::before {
  top: 0;
}
.menu__link::after {
  bottom: 0;
}
.menu:not(:focus-within):not(:hover) .menu__item .menu__link {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.menu__item {
  --pull: 30%;
}
.menu__item .menu__link {
  opacity: 0.25;
  transition-duration: calc(var(--td) * 3);
  transform: translate(0, calc(var(--pull) * -1));
}
.menu__item .submenu .menu__link {
  opacity: 1;
}
.menu__item:hover > .menu__link {
  color: #fb4d98;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.menu__item:hover > .menu__link:hover {
  color: var(--color-light);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.menu__item:hover ~ .menu__item > .menu__link {
  transition-duration: calc(var(--td) * 3);
  transform: translate(0, var(--pull));
}
@keyframes blink {
  50%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-container">
<input type="checkbox" id="main-navigation-toggle" class="btn btn--close" title="Toggle main navigation" />
<label for="main-navigation-toggle">
  <span></span>
</label>

<nav id="main-navigation" class="nav-main">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu__item">
      <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      <a class="menu__link" href="#0">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Projects</a>
   
</li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden` on body? When menu is opened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to enable & disable the scrolling of the page on the toggling of menu button. You can achieve this by using jQuery:

```
$('input[id="main-navigation-toggle"]').on('change',function(e) {
if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
} else {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
};
});
```

What this code will do is to check if the checkbox input with `id = main-navigation-toggle` you have provided is checked or not, if it's checked the `overflow` CSS property of body element will be set as `hidden` and if it's not checked then the `overflow` property will be set as `auto` which means the scrolling is enabled again when the menu is closed.

Comment: thanks i will try this, do i have to add "overflow: hidden" to the body in CSS as well then?

Comment: No, you don't need to do it. Otherwise, the scrolling will be disabled by default on the whole page.

Comment: This has worked thanks! Only issue is the scroll bar is hidden when you open the menu on desktop which makes it a bit jumpy, is there anyway to disable scroll while still showing the scroll bar? I can see this on other sites where the scroll bar remains in view but the actual clickable scroll part disappears so its just a white bar.

Comment: praveen - ive changed the menu now and it is no longer a checkbox, it just has a class of "menuclick", how would i amend your code above to make it work?

Comment: Can you share your code through an online IDE like codepen or create a new question & mention it there.

Comment: All that has changed is the html for the menu toggle, it has changed to this `<input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle-5efd83193c7ba" class="menu-toggle">` so i updated the first line of js to `$('input[id="menu-toggle-5efd83193c7ba"]').on('change',function(e) {` but it doesnt work?

Comment: @gjjr I tried that, its working as expected. There must be something else wrong in your code. It would be much helpful if you can share whole code on codepen.

Answer (score -1):

modify this class with this property

```
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
right: 2rem;
top: 0rem;
z-index: 100;
```

}

right value is changed,
i tried this
or if you want disable scroll

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: No, this is not margin from another element, this is right from screen, because it is position absolute

Comment: yes, but how does that achieve what I need - to disable scrolling when the menu is open

Comment: oh, i figure out, what you need, you can see my answer again, you can disable scroll when overflow: hidden for body @gjjr

Comment: It won't work. It will just disable the scroll for the whole page but I believe he wants the solution where when the menu is opened, only then the scroll is disabled and after closing the menu, the scrolling gets enabled.